# Error when restarting audio file using AVPlayer in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, avaudioplayer

In Swift 3, I want to play audio using `AVPlayer()` with functions for playing, pausing, and restarting the audio.

Working from a tutorial, the code in this view controller successfully **plays** and **pauses** but causes an error on restart:

```
import UIKit
//4 -
import AVKit
import AVFoundation

class Music1ViewController: UIViewController {

    //5 -
    var songPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()
    var player = AVPlayer()
    //15 -
    var hasBeenPaused = false


    @IBAction func play(_ sender: Any) {

        let playerItem = AVPlayerItem(url: URL(string: "https://s3.amazonaws.com/kargopolov/kukushka.mp3")!)
        player = AVPlayer(playerItem: playerItem)
        player.play()
    }

    @IBAction func pause(_ sender: Any) {

        player.pause()

    }

    @IBAction func restart(_ sender: Any) {
        //17 -
        if player.isPlaying || hasBeenPaused {
            player.stop()
            player.currentTime = 0

            player.play()
        } else  {
            player.play()
        }
    }
```

This draws an error: `Value of type 'AVPlayer' has no member 'isPlaying'`

Looking over the documentation, I don't see what I am missing, as I believe I have defined the variable for `player` and `AVPlayer` seems to accept status as part of its model.

Is there a preferred way to tell `AVPlayer` to start from a value (in this case, the 0 second mark of the audio file)?

Comment: Why don't you look up the documentation for isPlaying?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's true that AVPlayer doesn't have property of 'isPlaying' or 'playing' . I think you should use 'rate == 1' or 'timeControlStatus == AVPlayerTimeControlStatusPlaying'(iOS10 or higher) to check whether now is playing.